# How would you track a launch crash that looks like an authorized exit in a .Net application?

Tags: c#, c++, crash, launch

I am writing a game with XNA 4.0 and .Net 4.5.1. It works perfectly fine on most machines, but recently we identified two PCs, both of which have an AMD processor and Windows 10, where the game never launches at all.

This is how it goes: when the game is launched, the screen simply flashes for a split-second and then nothing happens. This is especialy weird because the .Net app (the game) has a `try/catch` over the main game loop, which usually captures all the possible crashes (and writes the details into a file).

Moreover, I made it so that the .Net app is actually launched by a simple c++ launcher. The c++ app uses `CreateProcess()` to run the game and then remains in the background with `WaitForSingleObject()` and if the game crashes without warning, it calls `GetExitCodeProcess()` to show user an error message.

This whole c++ setup has no effect! The game still makes the screen blink and nothing else. The Task Manager shows no game-related threads running after this.

Just to make it clear: the app does not launch either way: if I run it manualy (with .Net ".exe" file) or through the c++ launcher.

From what it seems, the game somehow finishes it's work in an authorized way, bypassing both the `try/catch` loop as well as the `WaitForSingleObject()` and `GetExitCodeProcess()`! And I have no idea even where to start searching for problems.

I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: anything in the eventlog in the computer the app crashes on?

Comment: Use DebugDiag to capture a crash dump from the process and then inspect it in WinDbg. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2580960

Comment: @KenTucker I have no idea how to use the event log on the computer, is there a way to create a dedicated filter or something for your app?

Comment: @xxbbcc There is no error, that's the whole point. I cannot enter any error into the DebugDiag.

Comment: @cubrman If the process crashes, you can capture a crash dump and analyze it. You don't "enter" an error into DebugDiag - you need to run it to capture the crash dump as the process crashes. If your process doesn't actually crash then you have a misleading question and you need to correct it.